# Which is the parallel structure?

Tags: grammaticality

> 1. The farther the sealing-wax is from the fire, the harder it is.
> 2. The farther from the fire, the harder the sealing wax.

I'd like to know which is the parallel structure.

Comment: Please tell us what you think _parallel structure_ means. When we know that, we will be better able to provide you with a helpful answer.

Comment: @P. E. Dant. I think parallel structure means the repetition of a chosen grammatical form within a sentence.

Comment: @theinlwin I am also having trouble understanding what you are asking, at least with regard to this example.  To me a "parallel" structure is something like "First I *drove* to the bank, then I *rode* to the post office, then I *walked* to the store, and then I *asked* for directions."

Comment: @Andrew I'd like to know whether my sentence examples are grammatical parallel structure or not.

Comment: @theinlwin if anything I'd say it's the same structure expressed two different ways.  A parallel would express two different thoughts using the same structure.  But I could be wrong.